# Чи можна зробити рандомними відповіді кнопки (KeyboardButton) в Телеграмм?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Роблю бота в Телеграмм, котрий буде грати в камінь,ножиці,папір. Були питання до рандому.
Проблема вирішилась легко. Але не зміг реалізувати підрахунок виграшів та програшів.
В принципі просто звертатись улавлюючи текст вашої кнопки.

```py
@dp.message_handler(text=["✊", "✌", "✋"])
    async def process_start1(message: types.Message):
        rand = ["✊", "✌", "✋"]
        rand = random.choice(rand)
        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 
    str(random.choice(rand)))
        if message.text == '✊' and rand == '✊':
            await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Нічія! Ще?')
        elif message.text == '✊' and rand == '✌':
            await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Перемога! ')
        elif message.text == '✊' and rand == '✋':
            await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Поразка! ')
        else:
            if message.text == '✌' and rand == '✊':
                await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Програш!')
                elif message.text == '✌' and rand == '✌':
                await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Нічія! ')
            elif message.text == '✌' and rand == '✋':
                await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Перемога!')
            else:
                if message.text == '✋' and rand == '✊':
                    await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id,'Перемога! ')

                elif message.text == '✋' and rand == '✌':
                    await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Програш! Відіграєшся?')
                elif message.text == '✋' and rand == '✋':
                    await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Нічия, давай ще!')
```

Comment: 1) Переведите вопрос на русский язык - это русскоязычный раздел SO 2) Приведите ваш код, к которому относится ошибка и полный трейс ошибки прямо в вопросе (важно понять, к какой именно строке кода она относится)

Comment: Добавьте в свой вопрос код программы. И переведите вопрос на русский.

Answer (score 1):

К счастью я украинец и каким-то чудом вас понял...
Итак, кода не вижу пишу примерно.

```
# импортируем функцию рандома
import random

# Функция просто возвращает из массива случайное значение
def rand_knb():
   arr = ["Камень", "Ножницы", "Бумага"]
   return arr[random.randint(0, 2)]

# Ну и хендлеры для самой игры
# Этот типо для запуска если пользователь вводит команду /start_game, то возвращает клавиатуру из трех кнопок
@dp.message_handler(commands="start_game")
async def send_welcome(msg: types.Message):
    markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup().add(
        InlineKeyboardButton("Камень", callback_data="knb:Камень"),
        InlineKeyboardButton("Ножницы", callback_data="knb:Ножницы"),
        InlineKeyboardButton("Бумага", callback_data="knb:Бумага")
    )
    await msg.answer("Началась игра.\n Выбери одну из кнопок.", reply_markup=markup)

# А вот эта обрабатывает нажатие из предыдущей клавиатуры.
@dp.callback_query_handler(text_contain="knb")
async def send_welcome(callback_query: types.CallbackQuery):
    # Это мы успакаиваем телеграмм что мы словили этот колбек
    callback_query.answer()
    # Это то что нажал игрок (Камень Ножницы Бумага)
    choise_player = callback_query.data.split(':')[1]
    # Это то что мы зарандомили
    choise_bot = rand_knb()
    # вот здесь сделай проверки по типу если игрок === камень а бот == ножницы то await callback_query.message.answer("Победа")
```

PS
А если вы хотели рандоминый текст в обычной кнопке, то думаю где-то так.

```
def rand_knb() -> str:
    arr = ["Камень", "Ножницы", "Бумага"]
    return arr[randint(0, 2)]



@dp.message_handler(commands="start_game")
async def send_welcome(msg: types.Message):
    markup = ReplyKeyboardMarkup().add(
        KeyboardButton(text=rand_knb())
    )
    await msg.answer("text", reply_markup=markup)
```

При таком хендлере при каждом вводе /start_game будет выводится кнопка с случайным текстом.

Comment: Охх.. Я немного не то сделал. Вы ведь просили не инлайн кнопки. В целом я думаю этот способ выглядит неплохо.

Comment: Друже, будь ласка. Переведи вопрос. я поправлю.